# autofocus on html tag using jsp and struts 1

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

I work with jsp and Struts 1.
  I need to set up the focus on login button in this page on load in order to make login faster.

This is my html form:

```
<html:form action="/someAction.do" method="post"> 
  <tr><td class="someClass" align=right>email: </td><td><html:text size="40" property="email"/><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="someClass" align=right>password: </td><td><html:password size="40" property="password"/><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td align=center colspan=2><br/>
    <html:submit value="login"/>
 </td></tr>
```

I've tried to do this:

```
<html:submit value="login" property="submit"/>
```

and then use javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementsByName("submit").focus();
}
```

And this is not working.

I wanted to use "Id" attribute for  tag but I don't know how can I do this in the Struts 1.
Does anyone know the Struts 1? ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `styleId`. For example -

```
UserName: <html:text property="userName" styleId="userName"></html:text>
PassWord: <html:password property="passWord" styleId="passWord"></html:password>
```